# Changes to the database schema are called migrations, what are data changes called?

Tags: migration, terminology

Not sure where to ask this but here it is anyway.

I understand that changes to the database schema are called *migrations* from a certain version to another.

What do DBAs call changes to the underlying data, ie. the sequence of `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`? Think of the MySQL binlog for instance. Is there a specific term for this?

Comment: Data manipulation operations ?

Comment: data migrations?

Comment: Where else, except Ruby on Rails, they are called _migrations_?

Comment: Scala also calls them so. Haskell too AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Check out DML - [Data Manipulation Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). This includes [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations (Create (i.e. INSERT - not to be confused with the CREATE TABLE statement below), Read (i.e. SELECT), Update, Delete) on Tables. It's what people associate most classically with SQL.

Compare this with DDL - [Data Definition Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language). DDL involves the CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE operations (among others - related to INDEXes amongst other things).

For completeness, there is also DCL - [Data Control Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_control_language). DCL is for the control of access to tables - GRANT and REVOKE (i.e. GRANT READ ON schema_name.table_name TO user_name.

The [SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=SQL) is an attempt to homogenise DML among various vendors - its success has been limited so far. Many servers implement non-standard extensions, their own Stored Procedure language, DDL and DCL. Take a look at the "Procedural extensions" section on the SQL page above.

Changes to a schema (from the same version of the same server to another or even within the same instance) are simply called DDL - CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE.

Changes to a schema brought about (normally) by an upgrade (e.g. Oracle 9 to Oracle 11) are called migrations - going the other way is called either downgrading or backward migration.

Changes to a schema due to a change of server (i.e. Oracle to SQL Server) are called ports ("porting"). These are normally quite difficult and involved due to the differences between servers mentioned above.